# How to copy text for variable from variable?

Tags: javascript

Here's a piece of code that works:

```
let js0 = document.getElementById('js0').value;
let nes0 = document.getElementById('nes0').value;
addEventListener('input', function() {
    document.getElementById('nes0').value = document.getElementById('js0').value;
});
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>JavaScript to NES Converter</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jstones.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="input">
        <h1>Input (.JS Format)</h1>
        <input type="text" id="js0">
        </div>
        <div id="output">
        <h1>Output (.ASM Format)</h1>
        <input type="text" id="nes0">
        </div>
        <script src="jstones.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And a piece of code that doesn't work:

```
addEventListener('input', function() {
    nes0 = js0;
});
```

I don't see the difference between nes0 = js0 and document.getElementById('nes0').value = document.getElementById('js0').value. Nes0 has the .value after document.getElementById('nes0'), as well as Js0.

What exactly am I doing wrong??

Comment: In example 2 you aren't changing the value property of a dom element, you're changing the value of a js variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to rewrite the code from the first example at the top of your question.

```js
addEventListener('input', function() {
  let js0 = document.getElementById('js0').value;
  document.getElementById('nes0').value = js0;
});
```

The reason that the second code does not work is because the code is simply changing the value of the variable `js0` to the value of `nes0` which is `""`.
These variables are then stored in memory and are not outputted to the page.
To get it to work you can change the statement so that instead of setting the variables to the values of the textboxes, you simply store a reference to the HTML elements:

> The getElementById() method of the Document interface returns an Element object representing the element whose id property matches the specified string.

> `document.getElementById('js0').value` - returns only a string

```js
addEventListener('input', function() {
  let nes0 = document.getElementById('nes0');
  let js0 = document.getElementById('js0');
  nes0.value = js0.value;
});
```

Then access the value of the elements by using `.value` after the variable referencing the element.
Hope this helps.